# create vectors from vector of names and assign length

Tags: r, vector, assign

I have a vector of names, like so:

```
sites <- paste("website", 1:10, sep = ".")
```

Using the names in the vector defined above, I would like to

1. create 10 vectors/variables, all of length `nrow(dataframe)`.
2. assign each vector a value of `NA`.

I understand how to use `assign` to give the variables specific values, but i can't seem to find a simple answer for how to create the variables themselves. Seems like an easy question but I can't find a straightforward answer.

The desired result is ten variables named `dataframe$website.1....dataframe$website.10`, with length of `nrow(dataframe)`. 
Thanks.

Comment: `as.data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow(dataframe), 10, dimnames = list(NULL, paste('website', 1:10, sep = '.'))))`  perhaps, though this seems the precursor to bad idioms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a vector of `NA`, you can do:

```
na_vector <- rep(NA, nrow(dataframe))
```

I'm not entirely clear what you're looking for after that, but if you want to add those `NA` vectors to a dataframe, one option is

```
for (s in sites) {
  dataframe[[s]] <- na_vector  # to add a column to a data frame
}
```